# Iterators of the same object do not operate independently

Tags: java, iterator, opencsv

I have a method comparing the content of two csv files. I use CSVReader.iterator() instead of loading each line with CSVReader.readNext() because of some problems I had when comparing the number of lines in the files. The method looks like this (check first comment - that was a 'hack' I used to make a workaround, but I am curious why it did not work without it):

```
public int compareTwoFiles(InputStream fileA, InputStream fileB) throws IOException {
    // I used this to fix the problem
    /*if (fileA == fileB) {
        return 1;
    }*/

    CSVReader readerA = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(fileA));
    CSVReader readerB = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(fileB));
    // empty file flag
    boolean empty = true;
    Iterator<String[]> iteratorA = readerA.iterator();
    Iterator<String[]> iteratorB = readerB.iterator();

    while (iteratorA.hasNext() && iteratorB.hasNext()) {
        String[] currentLineA = iteratorA.next();
        String[] currentLineB = iteratorB.next();
        // if lines length doesn't match - return 0
        if (currentLineA.length != currentLineB.length) {
            return 0;
        }

        else {
            for (int index = 0; index < currentLineA.length; index++) {
                // if the already checked part of file is empty, check if current cells are empty
                if (empty) {
                    // if one of the fields isn't empty, change empty flag
                    if (!currentLineA[index].equals("") || !currentLineB[index].equals("")) {
                        empty = false;
                    }
                }

                // if fields don't match - return 0
                if (!currentLineA[index].equals(currentLineB[index])) {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    if (iteratorA.hasNext() ^ iteratorB.hasNext()) {

        return 0;
    }

    if (empty) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This is the test that fails:

```
@Test
public void testSameNonEmptyFile() throws IOException {
    A = new ByteArrayInputStream("aaa,ddd,aaa".getBytes(_CHARSET));
    B = A;
    Assert.assertTrue(p.compareTwoFiles(A, B) == 1);
}
```

When I tried to manually debug it, it turned out, that iteratorA pointed to a String[] but iteratorB was null, which doesn't make any sense because they should work independently. Any thoughts?

Comment: Well of course: you're passing the same stream for both CSVs

Comment: Yes, I am trying to simulate comparing the file to itself

Comment: Well this will not work. You must create two distinct input streams (with the same content if you want to).

Comment: Thank you! That wasn't clear for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same stream to read the content twice. You should do:

```
byte[] content = "aaa,ddd,aaa".getBytes(_CHARSET);
A = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);
B = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you create `CSVReader` he do `CSVIterator` in constructor and do `next()`. You create two readers on the same object - and first reader do `next()`, and have next line as `String[]` and second reader havn't any line - cause first has it.

CsvIterator creates on each reader do:

```
  public CSVIterator(CSVReader reader) throws IOException {
     this.reader = reader;
     nextLine = reader.readNext();
  }
```

That's the answer of your question.